# Error "Unlinking directory not permitted" when I'm doing hg update with cygwin

Tags: mercurial, cygwin, branch, unlink

When I'm trying to **change the branch where I am**, I'm getting this error everytime:

```
# Just check in which branch I am
$ hg branch
django1.6

$ hg update --clean default
abandon: Unlinking directory not permitted: 'D:\Projects\abc\abc'
```

(`abc` is the project name, replace for simplicity here). Since it's a Django project, named `abc`, I have a subfolder `abc` that I have created in the `django1.6` branch. This folder **doesn't exist yet in the default branch**, so if I'm changing the branch, the folder has to be deleted in theory
When I check the properties, I see the folder is in read-only mode, so in cygwin I `chmod` the folder and try again...

```
$ chmod -R 0777 hstareal/
$ hg update --clean default
abandon: Unlinking directory not permitted: 'D:\Projects\abc\abc'
$ hg update --clean another-already-existing-branch
abandon: Unlinking directory not permitted: 'D:\Projects\abc\abc'
```

For information, I can create a branch and get back to `django1.6` without problems:

```
$ hg branch test
marked working directory as branch test
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)

$ hg update --clean django1.6
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Does anyone see where the problem is? I'm sure it's something related to cygwin, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single workaround I found for the moment is to delete the folder *by hand* and then update the branch.

```
$ rm -rf abc/
$ hg update --clean default
27 files updated, 0 files merged, 4 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Really dirty but at least it works... I'm still listening to better suggestions :)